# None of the lines after calling the "system()" function is running

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, terminal, system

After the line "command(system)", the next lines are not running. A new file "test1" is created but the next lines do no execute.

Using my linux Ubuntu terminal, I am trying to write a C program for opening a new file. Since the new file is created, it means that the system() function is working. But it does not stop executing.
If I close the terminal, it says "process is running". How do I stop the process? I do not get the linux terminal's line for command after a new file is created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char filename[50];

    printf("Enter the filename: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    // Create and open the file using the cat command
    char command[100];
    
    sprintf(command, "cat > %s", filename);
    system(command);
    printf("File '%s' created and opened.\n", filename);

    return 0;
}
```

[In the directory, a new file named "test1" is created but in the terminal, as you can see, the code doesn't finish executing/doesn't stop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8S0.png)

Comment: What is your actual goal? If it is just to create an empty file, you can do it with regular C file functions (`fopen()` etc.) rather than calling `system()`.

Answer (score 2):

> After the line "command(system)", the next lines are not running. A new file "test1" is created but the next lines do no execute.

They do not execute *yet*. That's because the `cat` command you are running via `system()` is waiting for input from its standard input.  The `system()` function will not return until `cat` terminates.  Typing Ctrl-D in the terminal window should make it stop waiting.

If all you want to do is create an empty file, then changing the command to redirect `cat`'s standard input would be one way to go about that:

```
    sprintf(command, "cat < /dev/null > %s", filename);
    system(command);
```

But if that's really all you want to do, then it would be more idiomatic to use `touch` instead of `cat`:

```
    sprintf(command, "touch %s", filename);
    system(command);
```

Comment: Or just `sprintf(command, ">%s", filename)`

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what your goal is here. If you just want to create an empty file, you can do it using the regular C standard library file functions, without calling out to a shell with `system()`.

Something like this might suffice:

```c
FILE *handle = fopen(filename, "w");
fclose(handle);
```

If the file already exists, but you want to "empty" it:

```c
truncate(filename, 0);
```

Calling `system()` to run some commands with file redirection is extremely non-portable and probably pointless. If you want to go down that path, just make a bash (or Python, or Ruby...) script.

Comment: Also `mknod()` may be used.

Comment: @dimich I knew the program, but not the function. Interesting.